# Bluetooth headphones disconnect when started in auto-connect mode

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, bluez

I am using the GNOME variant of Ultramarine Linux (a Fedora-based distro) version 39 as my primary Linux distro. I have a pair of headphones I bought for cheap from AliExpress. For some reason the headphones only work if I manually connect it. But if auto-connected it immediately disconnects. Here are the bluetoothctl logs when auto-connecting the speaker:

```
[bluetooth]#
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: yes
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

And when I manually connect it via bluetoothctl:

```
[bluetooth]# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Attempting to connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: yes
[NB-100]# [NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx/sep1 
[NB-100]# [NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx/sep2 
[NB-100]# [NEW] Endpoint /org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx/sep3 
[NB-100]# [NEW] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx/sep1/fd3 
[NB-100]# Connection successful
[NB-100]# [CHG] Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx/sep1/fd3 Volume: 0x007f (127)
[NB-100]# [CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ServicesResolved: yes
[NB-100]#
```

Does anybody knows why?